# Symfony ArrayCollection

Tags: symfony, orm, arraycollection

I have 2 entities:
`Category` and `Article` with the following relation:

- Each `Article` has **One** `Category`.
- Each `Category` may have **Many** `Article`.

**The problem** :

I want to add new category using this form :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
            'label' => 'Add a new category'
        ])
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Category::class,
    ]);
}
```

Here's the error I get when I enter a **string** value in the field name:

> `Name Error This value should be of type array|IteratorAggregate.`

I've never used `ArrayCollection` / Relation in symfony but I've tried to change the `TextType::class` to `CollectionType::class` it gives me a white square and I can't type anything.

In a more generic question : 
 **How could I validate values in a form without having the error : `This value should be of type array|IteratorAggregate.`**

```
Category

/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\Unique(message="Cette catégorie existe déjà")
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * @param $name
 * @return Collection|null
 */
public function setName($name): ?Collection
{
    return $this->name = $name;
}
```

Article

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
private $content;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $createdAt;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $image;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $editedAt;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category")
 */
private $category;
```

Comment: Are you sure that you need `article` property in the `Category` entity? Also check this [Doctrine's reference](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) and [Symfony's](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html)

Comment: Is that an standalone `CategoryType` form or is it embedded in `ArticleType`?

Comment: @EugeneRuban I used the symfony `php bin/console make:entity relation` to help me. It asked me if I would like to find every `Article` that belongs to a `Category` I said yes and it gave me the `articles` in the category

Comment: `CategoryType` form is standalone

Comment: So, just try to remove $article in the Category entity )

Comment: @EugeneRuban if I remove the relation it will work however I'm trying to understand, why I can't validate any form without having the error : `Error This value should be of type array|IteratorAggregate.` do I have to change something on my form, my entity ?

Comment: Because yours `Category` entity also have an `articles` property and with your form it gets `null`, so show me fully your `Category` entity, please. The error caused by setting `articles`, not `name` property.

Comment: @EugeneRuban oh ok, I thought that the whole entity was changed into a ArrayCollection. The full category entity is in the post, thanks for your time.

Comment: First, what I can see here and from our conversation in comments - you didn't need `$articles` property in the `Category` entity. You can remove it and to get all articles by Category - you should make it from standard `Article` repo.
Otherway, try to set `?Collection` in the getArticles() method

Comment: @EugeneRuban Yes I'm following a **symfony cast** course, it also says that only the **relation** `ManyToOne` is necessary. I removed it from the controllers like you told me (I edited the post) and I added `?Collection`. However I still encouter the same issue `This value should be of type array|IteratorAggregate.`. Thanks for your reply I'm really stuck